# How to link Facebook Page to Instagram page using a test user?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api

I am currently using a test user (created the facebook devs panel), to set up a fb page, that i need to link to another Instagram Business page.
I already created a fake ig business account using this test user. The proble is that every time i go to the fb business panel to link the other ig account [i get this this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAmQ9.jpg).

I need this because i have to go throw the App Review in order to get the permissions that i need for my app, in order to get aproved facebook tells you to record yourself with a test user doing all the app process. But i can´t do this if the test user doesnt have a IG Business account linked to it.

Comment: Please set your Facebook language to English, before you screenshot such errors. Questions here have be asked in English, and now you introduced information that is probably not understandable to many people here.

Comment: Page-related stuff is hard to test with test users; pages they create are separated from the rest of the environment. I would recommend that you record going through the whole flow with a _real_ user account that has a role in our app instead.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: They don't except with real users